# input type email validates without "require" attribute

Tags: javascript, html, validation, email

I have input field and I use type `email` to open keyboard with necessary symbols on mobile devices.

```
<input autofocus="" placeholder="E-mail" type="email">
```

But I don't need that browser validates it while submit. I didn't use `required` attirbute. But Chrome still says "Please include an `@` in the email address." on submit form. Is there any way to stop email validation on submit while using type="email"?

Comment: I [can't reproduce the problem you describe](http://jsbin.com/eGIKujID/1/)

Comment: Please [don't abuse the placeholder attribute](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/) like that.

Comment: use form attribute "novalidate" and validate form with your javascript code

Comment: @Quentin In your sample, I wrote `abc` and pressed submit, it says "Please include an @ in the email address."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

while submitting form include `novalidate` attribute

For eg:

```
<form action="demo.html" novalidate>
E-mail: <input autofocus="" placeholder="E-mail" type="email">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Form No-Validate :

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-fs-novalidate

```
<form action="editor.cgi" method="post">
 <p><label>Name: <input required name=fn></label></p>
 <p><input autofocus="" placeholder="E-mail" type="email"></p>
 <p><input type=submit formnovalidate name=save value="Save"></p>
</form>
```